# asp.net c# Treeview Drag and Drop

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

I'm looking for an ASP.NET solution to implement a drag-n-drop treeview in C#. Anyone can point me to some resources?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are few

**Open source**

[Jstree](http://www.jstree.com/) is an open source JQuery library

**Freeware**

And, [obout](http://www.obout.com/t2/edraganddrop.aspx) has a good control too

**Commercial**

[Telerik](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/treeview/examples/functionality/draganddropnodes/defaultcs.aspx) has a good treeview control